# Selenium: how to get text from alert from input field is mandatory for extjs

Tags: selenium, extjs

I'm automating an application in ExtJs. When an input filed is mandatory and user TABs out without entering values then an error message is shown as tool tip. how can i get the text "This field is required" from below?

```
<td id="numberfield-1909-inputCell" class="x-form-trigger-input-cell" style="width: 100%;">
<input id="numberfield-1909-inputEl" size="1" name="amount" maxlength="14" tabindex="40" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text x-form-invalid-field" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="true" data-errorqtip="<ul class=&quot;x-list-plain&quot;><li role=&quot;alert&quot;>This field is required</li></ul>" style="width: 100%;" type="text">
</td>
```

Comment: Your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions and will provide details next time. Anyways,
 I found the solution by using `getAttribute("data-errorqtip").getText()` and then had to extract the last 4 words.